# How to extract the out variables from a stored procedure in oracle?

Tags: node.js, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have stored procedure and there are many out variables in it. So I am calling the stored procedure like this:

```js
export const infoHR3 = async () => {
  try {
    const sql =
      ` 
      Declare
        ln_order_qty  NUMBER;
        ln_in_proc_qty_hr  NUMBER;
        ln_procd_hr_mass  NUMBER;
        ln_in_proc_qty  NUMBER;
        ln_wip  NUMBER;
        ln_qa  NUMBER;
        ln_packing  NUMBER;
        ln_dispatchable_qty  NUMBER;
        ln_despatched_qty  NUMBER;
        ln_finished_qty  NUMBER;
        ln_balance_qty  NUMBER;
        ln_bal_disp_qty  NUMBER;
      BEGIN
        CRMDBA.C1DVX007(
          '9514593782',
          '1',
          1,
          ln_order_qty,
          ln_in_proc_qty_hr,
          ln_procd_hr_mass,
          ln_in_proc_qty,
          ln_wip,
          ln_qa,
          ln_packing,
          ln_dispatchable_qty,
          ln_despatched_qty,
          ln_finished_qty,
          ln_balance_qty,
          ln_bal_disp_qty
        );
        dbms_output.put_line(ln_order_qty);
      END;  `;
    return await query(sql);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error.InternalServerError("Error!");
  }
};
```

This is the model:

```js
function getinfoHR3Table() {
  return infoHR3();
}
    
export const ProcessModel = {
      getProcess,
      getReason,
      getinfoHR1Table,
      getinfoHR2Table,
      getinfoCR1Table,
      getinfoCR2Table,
      getinfoHR3Table
};
```

This is the controller:

```js
export const getinfoHR3Table = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const results: any = await ProcessModel.getinfoHR3Table();
    return res.status(200).json(results);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json(error);
  }
};
```

The problem is I am getting blank value in the result. How do I extract out variables and return them when calling a stored procedure??

The problem with this is that `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` just prints line in the database. The procedure does not return any values which can be used in the backend. However it gives values to outvariables.

How can I extract these outvariables from the procedure so that I can use them in the backend?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the Node.js (I am assuming since you tagged that on the question) code you are using to call the procedure; and the signature for the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

Comment: I have edited the updated content from your duplicate question into your original; please review it to make sure the details are accurate (and next time, provide a [MRE] with all the code from the start and don't open a duplicate question).

Comment: ok sure thanks for that

Comment: Your PL/SQL procedure doesn't return any variables - there are no OUT binds.  If you want to get DBMS_OUTPUT see the two dbmsoutoput*.js examples in https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/main/examples and read the Doc https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#dbmsoutput

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Stored Procedure with arguments of type `IN OUT` in order to use the parameters in a versatile manner such as

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALL_C1DVX007(
                                          id IN NUMBER,
                                          in_prm1 IN NUMBER,
                                          in_prm2 IN NUMBER,
                                          ln_order_qty IN OUT NUMBER,
                                          ln_in_proc_qty_hr IN OUT NUMBER,
                                          ln_procd_hr_mass IN OUT NUMBER,
                                          ln_in_proc_qty IN OUT NUMBER,
                                          ln_wip IN OUT NUMBER,
                                          ln_qa IN OUT NUMBER,
                                          ln_packing IN OUT NUMBER,
                                          ln_dispatchable_qty IN OUT NUMBER,
                                          ln_despatched_qty IN OUT NUMBER,
                                          ln_finished_qty IN OUT NUMBER,
                                          ln_balance_qty  IN OUT NUMBER,
                                          ln_bal_disp_qty IN OUT NUMBER
                                        ) 
BEGIN
  CRMDBA.C1DVX007(id,
                  in_prm1,
                  in_prm2,
                  ln_order_qty,
                  ln_in_proc_qty_hr,
                  ln_procd_hr_mass,                  
                  ln_in_proc_qty,
                  ln_wip,
                  ln_qa,
                  ln_packing,
                  ln_dispatchable_qty,
                  ln_despatched_qty,
                  ln_finished_qty,
                  ln_ba lance_qty,
                  ln_bal_disp_qty);
END;
/
```

and call

```sql
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> BEGIN 
      CALL_C1DVX007(9514593782,1,1,:ln_order_qty,:ln_in_proc_qty_hr....);
     END;
     /
SQL> DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:ln_order_qty); -- to display a result coming from a parameter
```

from the command line

Comment: This is not answering the question I specifically asked how to return values this is just a round about way of doing what I did

Comment: WRONG! it does answer the question. What @BarbarosÖzhan has done is **exactly** what is required; changed the definition of the parameters.  Oracle requires that the calling process ***supply a variable to return the into***. This can be done only  by declaring a formal variable (parameter) as OUT or IN OUT.

Answer (score 0):

/*If ln_order_qty is the output variable from the procedure, you can capture the value of this variable into another variable and use it from there onwards.
Below is an example:-*/

`ln_order_qty_output := ln_order_qty;`

/* The above variable ln_order_qty_output will now contain the output variable value from the procedure and you can use it as a value in the backend PLSQL procedure */

```
    Declare
      ln_order_qty  NUMBER;
      ln_in_proc_qty_hr  NUMBER;
      ln_procd_hr_mass  NUMBER;
      ln_in_proc_qty  NUMBER;
      ln_wip  NUMBER;
      ln_qa  NUMBER;
      ln_packing  NUMBER;
      ln_dispatchable_qty  NUMBER;
      ln_despatched_qty  NUMBER ;
      ln_finished_qty  NUMBER;
      ln_balance_qty  NUMBER;
      ln_bal_disp_qty  NUMBER;
 BEGIN
```

CRMDBA.C1DVX007('9514593782','1',1,ln_order_qty,ln_in_proc_qty_hr,ln_procd_hr_mass,

```
 ln_in_proc_qty,ln_wip,ln_qa,ln_packing,ln_dispatchable_qty,ln_despatched_qty,
 ln_finished_qty,ln_balance_qty,ln_bal_disp_qty);
 ln_order_qty_output := ln_order_qty;    
 dbms_output.put_line(ln_order_qty);    
 dbms_output.put_line(ln_order_qty_output);    
END;
```

/*Both the values displayed on the dbms_output.put_line should be the same
You can now use the value of the variable ln_order_qty_output in the
backend
*/

Comment: No this is not working it is showing you must declare line order qnty output .